# Umbraco razor template - Get Formatted Date From Field specified in parameter

Tags: razor, umbraco

I'm trying to return a formatted date from a razor template in umbraco.  I'm not sure how to get a value from a field defined in a parameter though.

Here is the code I'm playing with.  The field I'm passing in is called "articleDate".  I'm getting the parameter value output, however when I try to get the value of the field using the parameter name it returns nothing.  If I ask for the value by the field name itself, that works.  How can I create a generic macro like this?

```
@{var param = @Parameter.dateField;}
Field Name: @param
<br/>
Field Value: @Model.param
<br/>    
Field Value: @Model.articleDate
```

I tried using @Model.GetDynamicMember(..) as well, but that just throws an exception.

```
Field Value: @Model.GetDynamicMember("articleDate");​

Error loading Razor Script getDate.cshtml
Cannot invoke a non-delegate type
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?  I'm just trying to create a simple macro I can use to format dates across my page.

Is it possible to pass the value of my date directly into the razor macro?  This is how I'm currently calling it:

```
<umbraco:Macro ID="Macro1" Alias="getDate" dateField="articleDate" runat="server"></umbraco:Macro>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you call your Macro like you wrote:

```
<umbraco:Macro ID="Macro1" Alias="getDate" dateField="articleDate" runat="server"></umbraco:Macro>
```

You're actually passing the name of the field "articleDate". In the macro, you then may get the value of the Model's articleDate property by using:

```
Field Value: @Model.getProperty(Parameter.dateField).Value
```

Instead of macro's I also recommend using **helpers** or - for more complex scripts - **RenderPage**. A nice writeup can be found here:
http://joeriks.wordpress.com/2011/03/11/better-structure-for-your-razor-scripts-with-renderpage-in-umbraco/

Example:

```
@helper GetDate(dynamic dateField)
{
     @dateField.ToString("[yourFormat]")
}
```

You may pass parameters to scripts rendered with RenderPage by using the Page object:

```
<umbraco:macro language="razor" runat="server">
@{
    Page.dateField=Model.articleDate;
}
@RenderPage("~/macroscripts/getdate.cshtml")
</umbraco:macro>
```

getdate.cshtml:

```
@Page.datefield.ToString("[yourFormat]")
```